# Do disintegrated enemies respawn?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, fallout-3

I noticed that some goo puddles seem to be permanent in my games, and that some powder gangers I turned to goo many levels ago haven't respawned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known [glitch](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Ash/Goo_Pile_Problem) where Goo puddles never disappear, it's possible this is the reason why you never see them despawn.

Most areas stay the way you left it for about 72 in-game hours. There are some exceptions, as noted on this [forum post](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Do_enemies_respawn_at_all?). Generally it seems that outside areas that have random encounters respawn, whereas inside areas don't. Have a look at this [Power Leveling guide](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_power_leveling) - It provides a list of many areas where enemies respawn.

If you want enemies to respawn quickly, you'll need to sleep or wait for 72 hours in-game.

Answer (score 8):

[Goo puddles don't despawn](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Ash/Goo_Pile_Problem) - it's a glitch/bug which was never really handled.

As for respawning enemies, there's a discussion [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Do_enemies_respawn_at_all?) about which enemies do respawn and which don't. Mostly, if 72 in game hours pass, respawning baddies will have respawned.

Comment: ack, beat me by about 4 mins :)

Comment: @Robotnik apparently that doesn't matter :/

Comment: ah well, you're getting all the upvotes anyway :)